# ndarray rows are not displayed each one per line

Tags: python, numpy, formatting, format, numpy-ndarray

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.matrix([[-4.41991030e-05,-9.27712599e-04,3.75797779e-04,4.11804326e-04,1.08815444e-04],
        [-3.58432112e-04,-6.11583291e-04,1.18565910e-03,4.10337098e-04,9.96854953e-05],
        [-1.36865905e-03,1.19013259e-03,1.62785645e-03,1.85052363e-04,6.73256050e-05],
        [-0.00292639,-0.0084904,-0.00337932,-0.00014984,0.0001385]])

print(M)
```

When I run it, each row is divided in two lines, although the terminal is in full screen mode:

[image]

Even when I save it to a file, using this part of code :

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in M:
        f.write(str(row))
        f.write('\n')
```

I got the same problem:

[image]

I tried to open the file with different editors, but I had the same output format, so I ended up to that the problem is not related to text editors, that's why I posted my question here.
Any one here knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` sets the max line width by default to `75` you can change this using `set_printoptions(linewidth = some_num)`, see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
In[17]:
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=700)
M = np.matrix([[-4.41991030e-05,-9.27712599e-04,3.75797779e-04,4.11804326e-04,1.08815444e-04],
        [-3.58432112e-04,-6.11583291e-04,1.18565910e-03,4.10337098e-04,9.96854953e-05],
        [-1.36865905e-03,1.19013259e-03,1.62785645e-03,1.85052363e-04,6.73256050e-05],
        [-0.00292639,-0.0084904,-0.00337932,-0.00014984,0.0001385]])

print(M)

[[-4.41991030e-05 -9.27712599e-04  3.75797779e-04  4.11804326e-04  1.08815444e-04]
 [-3.58432112e-04 -6.11583291e-04  1.18565910e-03  4.10337098e-04  9.96854953e-05]
 [-1.36865905e-03  1.19013259e-03  1.62785645e-03  1.85052363e-04  6.73256050e-05]
 [-2.92639000e-03 -8.49040000e-03 -3.37932000e-03 -1.49840000e-04  1.38500000e-04]]
```